How to send a shutdown command to specific NUT clients
I'm attempting to setup Network UPS Tools server for my Proxmox and Windows clients. Using a Raspberry Pi as the NUT-server, I'd like to know how to send shutdown commands to specific clients. Each client has its own battery (sometime have two), and I'd like to be able to shut them down independently of one another in case not all UPSes are down.
The only method I found to request clients shutdown is upsmon, setting the -c fsd flag will "shutdown all primary-mode UPSes (use with caution)". This however is not what I want for the majority of cases. My Raspberry Pi is separately powered and will last much, much longer than my main systems. I would only want to use this command if the Raspberry Pi's UPS can't sustain itself.
I figure a solution to this is by generating SSH certs and allow the Raspberry Pi to connect and run a shutdown command, however this won't work on the Windows machine (I'd rather not put a SSH server on the Windows machine).
Any help is much appreciated.
